# Searching for a book or author in a database table

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, search

I have a data table listings books, which has columns for author, title, etc like in a library or Amazon.

How can I create a search for author or title of the books, like you would when trying to find a specific book in a library or Amazon?

I am using visual studio and access to construct the project.

I am quite new to VB, so I am sorry if this is a easy or stupid question.

Comment: what you have  tried?

Comment: Are you asking for the SQL query or the whole process of connection from vb.net to fetch the data from db?

Answer (score 0):

You can put this in your query.

```
  SELECT * FROM books WHERE title LIKE '%"& Me.TextBox1.Text &"%' OR
  author LIKE '%"& Me.TextBox1.Text &"%'
```

Comment: OP said "I am using visual studio and access to construct the project.", so only the query isn't enough to get the data!